# Remove One Item From Array In BehaviorSubject Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to remove a specific element from my array when the user clicks it however, it seems to be deleting them all. I have tried using splice on the dataService specifically but I am not able to do that, I get an error saying "Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'Observable< any>'" I am trying to figure out how to remove one element from the dataService specifically, based off of the Object passed to it from the HTML. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
footer.component.ts

```
export class FooterComponent {
  nominations = [];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.currentNoms.subscribe(noms => {this.nominations.push(noms);});
  }
  ngOnInit(): void{
    
  }
  remove(nom: Object): any{
    this.nominations.splice(this.nominations.indexOf(nom), 1);
    console.log(nom);
    console.log(this.nominations);      
  }

}
```

footer.component.html

```
<div class="nominationsDisplay">
    <div id="nominations" *ngFor="let nom of nominations[0]">
        <img src={{nom.Poster}}/>
        <button class="removeBtns" type="submit" (click)="remove(nom)">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

data.service.ts

```
export class DataService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addNominations(nom: Object){
    this.finalNoms.next(nom);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead try this:

footer.component.html

```
<div class="nominationsDisplay">
    <div id="nominations" *ngFor="let nom of nominations[0]; let i = index">
        <img src={{nom.Poster}}/>
        <button class="removeBtns" type="submit" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`TS File`

```
remove(index: number): any{
    this.nominations.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(nom);
    console.log(this.nominations);      
  }
```

What I did was, I passed the index on the button click, and spliced using the index. Try this and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! That removes it from the array within the footer.component.ts, but I now need to figure out how to remove it from the data.service.ts array that I am using between my components. the currentNoms is the array I need to remove items from but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can pass the use the index to find retrieve the Nominations object present in the array and use that id and then remove it using the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the item in your **service.ts**

```typescript
export class DataService {

  private finalNoms = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentNoms = this.finalNoms.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addNominations(nom: Object){
    this.finalNoms.next(nom);
  }

  removeNominations(nom: Object) {
    const newArray = [...this.finalNoms.value];
    newArray.splice(this.nominations.indexOf(nom), 1);
    this.finalNoms.next(newArray)
  }

}
```

In your **FooterComponent.ts**

```typescript
  remove(nom: Object): any{
    this.dataService.removeNominations(nom)     
  }
```

Now all subscribers will be notified of this change